Raspberry Shake and Boom Down: What I tried. What else I can try?
I noticed on October 25 that my Raspberry Shake (AM.R3635) is down. It has been working fine for last several years and nothing changed in terms of internet connectivity.
All the lights are glowing as they should be.

I unplugged it and plugged it after an hour and still it remains online.

FING detects the device on my network and its IP address. I am able to ping it without any packet loss.

I am NOT able to access the device locally on my network using the IP address that FING detects.

I also took out the SD card and reinserted it.

I tried accessing it through SSH (by installing Putty. But the username: pi and password: raspberry does not work.


Any other suggestions on what I can do. Thanks.

have you read the friendly manual

"Any other suggestions on what I can do." -> Yes, plug in a screen and keyboard so you can diagnose the problem properly.  Otherwise you are mostly just wasting your time and might as well just cross your fingers and hope the problem goes away.

check your LAN .

Thank you everyone. I was able to make the Raspberry Shake and Boom work. I reformatted the SD Card using DISKSPACE and the reburnt the code on the SD. And voila it started to work.
